# Let's clean up our tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We have *67* tags that are on only one question. That's a lot.  A good bit of these tags are unneeded, though not all.

Let's try to clean those up.

[Here's a list of all these tags](https://paste.ee/p/2Efgp). (I would make a SEDE query, but apparently we're not on there yet)

Some of these can easily go (for example, we had 68 until I removed [rheumatoid-arthritis](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rheumatoid-arthritis)), but others are not so clear.

For example, [hypervitaminosis](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypervitaminosis) is probably not a good choice. A good rule of thumb is whether the tag can be the only tag on a question.  Can [hypervitaminosis](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypervitaminosis) do that? Not really, it's more or less a subset of [health](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health).

Another good rule of thumb: Is the tag likely to be used again later? For example, will [bivalves](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bivalves) ever be used again? Honestly, probably not. And furthermore, even if it's used only a couple times per year, it's pretty easy to create it and retroactively retag applicable questions.

I'll be slowly working on poring through these tags and looking at them, feel free to help. Remember only to edit 3-4 at a time, if applicable, to keep the front page clean. (tag edits bump questions)

If you have any particular tags you feel that need special attention, post an answer to this question describing the tag, what we should do with it and why, and how it's going to be used (with a sample tag wiki).

Note: I'm not trying to say all of these single-question tags are bad, or that they're bad for that reason. However, some of them can definitely go.

Comment: After a little bit of untagging, I actually think the rest look reasonably ok for now...

Comment: @Zanna yeah, so do I.

Answer (score 3):

Sloooow down. Just because they're only used on one question so far, doesn't automatically make it a bad tag - just that this is still a new site and doesn't have a ton of questions. Don't remove them just because they're only used once; make a decision for each tag. Don't be hasty; don't remove them just because they've only been used once.

Comment: agree totally. I've also been trying to keep tags clean as questions are posted

Answer (score 2):

[Synonym suggestion](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags/substitutes/synonyms)

[alternative](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative) (1 question) → [substitute](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitute) (11 questions)

Answer (score 2):

Synonym suggestion (but I don't have enough points to suggest)

[traveling](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling) → [travel](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel)

Answer (score 1):

There are also a few tag synonyms that could be created.

- [nutrition](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) <- [nutrient-requirements](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrient-requirements)
- [traveling](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling) <- [vegetarian-tourism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarian-tourism)
- [raw](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw) <- [rawfood](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood)

Comment: I've gone ahead and merged the first two (somebody must have already edited the first out, which I might end up rolling back for the purposes of synonymizing), which includes making a synonym. Thanks for letting me know about those.

Comment: Wait, I found the problem. It's [tag:rawfood] not [tag:raw-food]. However, I'm not sure which one I want to merge. I've [created a synonym](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags/rawfood/synonyms), but it's up to the community to vote on it.

Comment: One way or another we should be consistant. We have [tag:vegan-diet], and [tag:vegetarian-diet] following a *-diet convention. We also have [tag:veganism] and [tag:fruitarianism] following an *ims convention, and then [tag:raw] and [tag:ovo-lacto] which have no suffix. Maybe a seperate question about suffixes would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sooner or later to make Meta easier to grasp it's also good to clean the Meta tags. I recommend that:

- The total number of distinct tags should be minimized or regularized
- Every Meta topic should have at least one tag apart from [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

You want that if you want to find and read everything that's been written on Meta, about a given topic like [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).