# Let's rename the [raw] tag to [rawfood-diet]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [raw](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw) tag currently describes two distinct sets of questions. I think the questions should be tagged differently, as described below.

**Raw Food Diets** - I suggest creating a new [rawfood-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood-diet) tag to use for this group. These questions are about diet patterns that totally or mostly exclude cooked/heated food.

- [Raw food veganism - maintaining energy levels as an older athlete](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/raw-food-veganism-maintaining-energy-levels-as-an-older-athlete)
- [What are the health benefits of raw veganism?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/527/what-are-the-health-benefits-of-raw-veganism)
- [Is there any evidence that vegan and/or rawfood diets are beneficial to people that suffer from rheumatoid arthritis?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/315/is-there-any-evidence-that-vegan-and-or-rawfood-diets-are-beneficial-to-people-t)

**Raw Foods** - I suggest keeping the [raw](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw) tag for this group. These are about preparing and eating specific foods without heat, but do not imply the exclusion of cooked foods. Personally, this would make me more comfortable about using the tag.

- [What are the health benefits of eating citrus fruits with their peels?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/180/what-are-the-health-benefits-of-eating-citrus-fruits-with-their-peels)
- [Are raw potatoes good for a snack?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-raw-potatoes-good-for-a-snack)
- [Why is the temperature limit for raw food set to 42 C / 108 F?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/554/why-is-the-temperature-limit-for-raw-food-set-to-42-c-108-f)

#### Historical perspective:

- We already agreed that [raw food diets are on-topic](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4/1236).
- We have tags for other diet patterns such as [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) [ovo-lacto](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ovo-lacto) and [fruitarianism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruitarianism)
- We originally had a [rawfood](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood) tag but it was [dropped](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/posts/554/revisions) in favour of just using [raw](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw)
- [rawfood](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood) was [suggested as a synonym](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/156/1236) for [raw](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-tagged a bunch of questions yesterday with [rawfood-diet](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rawfood-diet). This is done now.